# TinyMCE align tag

Tags: javascript, tinymce, alignment

I am upgrading from a very old version of TinyMCE to the latest version. In the old TinyMCE, anytime you inserted an image and left aligned it, the HTML generated would be something to the effect of:

```
< img src="testing.jpg" align="left" >
```

However in the new version of TinyMCE, it is instead doing:

```
< img src="testing.jpg" style="float: left" >
```

Unfortunately when this HTML is rendered in Outlook, it does not display correctly. Any thoughts on how I can fix this issue without having to modify any core TinyMCE code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

When you call init, you can pass a format option like this:

```
formats : {
            alignleft : {attributes : {align : "left"}}
          }
```

See if this works for you. More documentation on this [here](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3aformats)

EDIT: Evidently you also need to use selectors to specify which elements these rules should apply to:

```
alignleft : {selector : 'img', attributes :{align : "left"} }
```

You can see a working fiddle [here](http://fiddle.tinymce.com/7ncaab)

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work, TinyMCE generates this:
< p >< img style="float: left;" src="http://theminorityreport.co/stixblog/files/2012/03/MOTIVATIONAL-POSTER-OF-THE-DAY-ninja-pirates-5169421-600-480.jpg" alt="" width="600" height="480" />< /p >

Comment: You're right, I had to make a couple changes. Try the fiddle.